# cv2.imdecode returns None when trying to read bytestring image

Tags: python, opencv

I use this function to read a png and convert it into a byte array.

```
def generate_data(file):
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, file))
    img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(img_byte_arr, format="png")
    byte_arr = img_byte_arr.getvalue()
    return byte_arr

file1 = generate_data("file1.png")
file1 = np.fromstring(file1, np.uint8)
```

The np.array before looks like this: `np.array: [98 39 92 ... 56 50 39]`

```
file1 = cv2.imdecode(file1, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

file1: None
```

Why does `cv2.imdecode(file1, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)` return None

Can anyone help me and explain why?

Comment: It looks like `img.save` is not working as it should have. PNG [file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) is 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47, in decimal it is `137`, `80`, `78`, `71` and you are getting `98 39 92`... Please add the `import` statements, and try to make the problem reproducible. I may suggest creating a sample input image file by code. Don't use `PROJECT_ROOT`.

Comment: I thought you should have used `file1 = np.frombuffer(file1, np.uint8)` instead of `file1 = np.fromstring(file1, np.uint8)`, but I see it's also working with `fromstring`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do?

Your code seems to read and decode a PNG image from disk into a PIL Image, then re-encode it back into a PNG in memory in a BytesIO. There's no point - you already had a PNG-encoded image on disk! If you want a PNG-encoded image in memory from a PNG-encoded file on disk, just do:

```
import pathlib

PNGencodedImage = pathlib.Path('image.png').read_bytes()
```